# ex.ter.nal.ip:8081 changes to localhost:8081

Tags: windows-7, networking, localhost, windows-services

Asked this question on Server Fault before, but got redirected to here. Hope this is the right place to ask this question.

I installed YouTrack from Jetbrains on my Windows 7 machine, which works just fine. Now I want to make this running service available for 'the outside world'.
Due some network problems at home, I had to make an subnetwork for all my own devices (including this windows 7 machine running YouTrack).

`ex.ter.nal.ip -> Modem -> 192.168.178.27 (my router) -> 192.168.0.115 (windows 7)`

I think I did setup the forwarding correctly, using DMZ. My modem DMZ to my router, which DMZ to Windows 7. So every port filled in from the `ex.ter.nal.ip` is forwarded to my windows 7 machine. Correct?

Now as I've said before, I'm running a YouTrack Service which is accessible from my Windows at `localhost:8081`. With my current setup, I would say this service is reachable at `ex.ter.nal.ip:8081`. But then happens (for me) something weird.
The URL changes from `ex.ter.nal.ip:8081` to `localhost:8081`.
So my MacBook is looking for it's own localhost.

I really don't get what is happening here.
In some tutorial I followed I had to make a rule in the firewall, but I disabled this because I thought this could be the problem. But, nevertheless...

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was an issue for YouTrack and had nothing to do with my network setup.

I had to change the base-url.

http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-585